# What are the popular methodologies to minimize data snooping?

Tags: backtesting, strategy

Are there common procedures prior or posterior backtesting to ensure that a quantitative trading strategy has real predictive power and is not just one of the thing that has worked in the past by pure luck? Surely if we search long enough for working strategies we will end up finding one. Even in a walk forward approach that doesn't tell us anything about the strategy in itself.

Some people talk about white's reality check but there are no consensus in that matter.

Comment: Testing on "out of band" data (data you didn't use to come up w/ the strategy) is a common approach. The problem "if we search long enough for working strategies we will end up finding one" is actually more serious. If you have a parameterized strategy, you can just tweak the parameters to make the strategy more accurate.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "tweak the parameters". What I do is look at the robustness of the strategy by changing the parameters arround my prefered values. The problem with this approach is that it is difficult to build a proper quatitative test to reject or not the strategies robustness. What is the size of the radius of the hypersphere arround the prefered value one has to look at? What performance variation should we tolerate? At the end it is almost just how you feel about it. I believe that to be dangerous in quant trading.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Strictly speaking, data snooping is *not* the same as in-sample vs out-of-sample model selection and testing, but has to deal with *sequential* or *multiple* tests of hypothesis based on the *same* data set. To quote Halbert White:

> Data snooping occurs when a given set
>   of data is used more than once for
>   purposes of inference or model
>   selection. When such data reuse
>   occurs, there is always the
>   possibility that any satisfactory
>   results obtained may simply be due to
>   chance rather than to any merit
>   inherent in the methody yielding the
>   results.

Let me provide an example. Suppose that you have a time series of returns for a single asset, and that you have a large number of candidate model families. You fit each of these models, on a test data set, and then check the performance of the model prediction on a hold-out sample. If the number of models is high enough, there is a non-negligible probability that the predictions provided by one model will be considered good. This has nothing to do with bias-variance trade-offs. In fact, each model may have been fitted using cross-validation on the training set, or other in-sample criteria like AIC, BIC, Mallows etc. For examples of a typical protocol and criteria, check Ch.7 of Hastie-Friedman-Tibshirani's "[The Elements of Statistical Learning](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/)". Rather the problem is that implicitly multiple tests of hypothesis are being run *at the same time*. Intuitively, the criterion to evaluate multiple models should be more stringent, and a naive approach would be to apply a [Bonferroni correction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonferroni_correction). It turns out that this criterion is too stringent. That's where [Benjamini-Hochberg](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~ybenja/MyPapers/benjamini_hochberg1995.pdf), [White](http://weber.ucsd.edu/~hwhite/pub_files/hwcv-077.pdf), and [Romano-Wolf](http://www-stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~steele/Courses/956/Resource/MultipleComparision/RomanoWolf05.pdf) kick in. They provide efficient criteria for model selection. The papers are too involved to describe here, but to get a sense of the problem, I recommend Benjamini-Hochberg first, which is both easier to read and truly seminal.

Answer (score 18):

Building an effective backtest is not significantly different than building any other kind of predictive model.  The goal is to have similar behavior *out of sample* as you have *in sample*.  As such, there are methodologies developed in statistics and machine learning that can be useful:

- Understand the bias/variance tradeoff.  This is covered in many places.  For a technical discussion, see [lecture 9 of Andrew Ng's machine learning class at Stanford](http://videolectures.net/stanfordcs229f08_ng_lec09/).
- You can certainly use a training and test dataset.  But there are also other kinds of approaches that can be used.  To list two common options: [cross-validation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_%28statistics%29) (similar to having segmented data, but can help with parameter selection) and [ensemble methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning_ensemble) (using multiple models can outperform just one and further reduce the curve-fitting problem).

So a few general recommendations:

1. Your guiding principle should be [**Einstein's razor**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor#Science_and_the_scientific_method):  'Everything should be kept as simple as possible, but no simpler.'  In other words, less degrees of freedom in your model equates to less chance for overfitting.  In the statistics world, this can involve eliminating unnecessary parameters through a [selection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_selection) or [regularization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularization_%28mathematics%29) method.
2. **Robustness** (in every respect) is also critical.  Parameters that result in sharp changes in expected prediction error will be more open to the risk of overfitting.  Similarly, if the model has no fundamental basis, then it should be applicable to a wide number of assets.
3. Lastly, this applies to any kind of model: understand your data, your model, your objectives, assumptions, etc.  There have been countless mistakes made over time from people not understanding the meaning of their models, implications, and risks.  This includes things like execution assumptions and transaction costs.  Make sure that you take everything into account.  Lead by being skeptical of your data, constantly asking what can go wrong, or how can the future be different.  Is there any [survivorship bias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survivorship_bias) in your data, and if so, how can you control for it?  Have you introduced any look-ahead bias?

Answer (score 10):

I have seen Hansen's SPA ('Superior Predictive Ability') test and stepwise variants used for this purpose. Hansen's test is a Studentized version of White's Reality Check. The stepwise variants allow one to accept or reject the null of no predictive ability on a subset of some tested strategies while maintaining a familywise error rate.

In his book, 'Evidence-Based Technical Analysis,' David Aronson discusses the overfit bias very well, although I believe his techniques for minimizing the bias may only apply to technical strategies, because they rely on Monte Carlo simulations.

**References**

- P. R. Hansen, 'A Test for Superior Predictive Ability,' Journal of Business
  & Economic Statistics, vol 23, no 4, 2005, [http://pubs.amstat.org/doi/abs/10.1198/07350010
  5000000063](http://pubs.amstat.org/doi/abs/10.1198/073500105000000063).
- [SPA google group](http://groups.google.com/group/testing-for-superior-predictive-ability)
- Hsu, Po-Hsuan, Hsu, Yu-Chin and Kuan, Chung-Ming, 'Testing the Predictive 
  Ability of Technical Analysis Using a New Stepwise Test Without Data Snooping 
  Bias,' 2008, http://ssrn.com/abstract=1087044
- Hsu, Po-Hsuan and Hsu, Yu-Chin, 'A Stepwise SPA Test for Data Snooping and its 
  Application on Fund Performance Evaluation,' 2006, http://ssrn.com/abstract=885364
- [David Aronson's Evidence-Based TA](http://www.evidencebasedta.com/).

Answer (score 7):

The output of your model will be a realization of your assumptions. Shane's given you a great answer. Besides doing out of sample testing (i.e., calibrating on period X then testing in period Y only using info available at the time of each trade), I would add that you should test it in sub-periods. If you have a big chunk of data, break it up and see how it works on each subset of the data.

Comment: Comparing stability across sub periods and visualizing the parameter changes across sub periods is a good place to start

Answer (score 7):

This blog post points to a presentation about backtesting and data snooping: http://www.portfolioprobe.com/2010/11/05/backtesting-almost-wordless/

I think the only non-datasnooping method there is is to trade live.  But the problem of data snooping can be reduced by seeing how significant the backtest result is compared to what would have happened if the trades were random.  Using this technology also makes it clear that backtesting results can easily be deceiving.

Answer (score -2):

Thanks for the answer as it tackles a lot of backtesting flaws, model parsimony, overfitting, survivorship bias, look ahead...
But actually one can look at thousands of technical trading rules and other more sofisticated strategies, and maybe find the few ones that will answer all these problems. Nevetheless we would still be left with data snooping ie we have used our data set untill we find a satisfactory result.

Comment: You will always have variance in your out of sample performance because *the future isn't exactly like the past*.  There's a reason that this is *hard*.

Comment: For reference: your answer here would generally be better as a comment on an existing answer.

Comment: I think that even if one can completly cancel the data snooping bias that wouldn't cancel the variance between backtested and true results. This is due to non stationarity and we cannot do anything about that. Ok for the comments

Comment: Do you view data snooping as different than overfitting?

Comment: Yes I maybe wrong but I view these problems as close but yet different. Well if we try to find the best parameters (with maximum likehood, MSE, MAP) and actually fit the predicted time serie to noise instead of real "structure" or "pattern", we have overfitted. In the contest of backtesting I see the data snooping as the bias we introduce when looking for different rules untill we find a working one.

Comment: @Zarbouzou I would be interested to know more about what you mean there.  Maybe either add a new answer or edit your question to go into more detail about this distinction?

Comment: @Zarbouzou I posted a follow up question here: http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/147/what-are-the-key-risks-to-the-quantitative-strategy-development-process.  Maybe provide an answer on this distinction there?